# Why does ggplot not plot when storing to variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, read-eval-print-loop

I thought this was obvious, but recently I was using the package `openair` and noticed that when I run the following:

```
library(openair)
myplot <- windRose(mydata)
```

the plot `myplot` is still plotted in the viewer. After looking at the `windRose` function it is obvious the `plot` function is being called.

However, why does `myggplot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_point()` not have the same outcome of plotting to the viewer. I am guessing the difference is in how these functions are programmed but I cannot easily identify how ggplot handles the plotting part.

Comment: ggplot, and anything else built on top of the grid system, like lattice, has to be `print`ed. So you either call `print` explicitly, or you just type it at the console to "display" it which causes R to call `print` on it behind the scenes.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a ggplot-specific behavior, but a more general principle: **The R REPL doesn't print assignment statements in general**, whereas for expressions, it calls `print()` or `show()` on the resulting value, depending on the object type (see [Autoprinting section of R Internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Autoprinting) for details).  For example,<sup>**1**</sup>

```
> 1 + 1       # expression
[1] 2
> x <- 1 + 1  # assignment
>
```

For a ggplot object, calling `print` on the object triggers a rendering. So, if you don't assign, it gets rendered.  For example,

```
> ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

```
> g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) + geom_point()
>
```

The `plot` function, on the other hand, includes rendering as part of it, which is why the other function you called gets rendered despite the assignment.

Note that one can use the `invisible` function to temporarily set `R_Visible` to `FALSE`, which turns off the default behavior of printing expressions, but will still push the evaluated result to `.Last.value`.

```
> invisible(1 + 1)
> .Last.value
[1] 2
```

However, because `plot()` calls a render to the graphics device as part of its code, `invisible()` will not stop it from rendering.

```
> invisible(plot(mtcars$hp, mtcars$mpg))
```

[image]

---

<sup>**[1]** Credit [@Gregor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903061/gregor)</sup>